# IE8: Floats not working correctly in Print CSS

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8

Does IE8 support floats in print css? I can't seem to get mine to work, I have a two column layout:

```
#container {
   width: 95% !important;
   margin: 0 auto !important; 
}

#main-view {
  width: 400px !important;
  float: left !important;
}

.confirmation-sidebar {
  width: 210px !important;
  margin: 1% 0 !important;
  float: left !important;
}
```

The container div is 100% of the window. There is more than enough room for these elements to float, so the widths shouldn't be an issue. I can't wrap my head around this silly problem.

They float fine in the website, but when print css is applied they are not floating correctly. Only half of the sidebar floats right, then the rest appears at the bottom of the page.

I have this working fine in Chrome (OSX & Win), FF (OSX & Win), Safari, Opera (OSX)

Comment: Your main view is 400px wide, the floated sidebar is 210px wide, is this nested within main view? Can you post you html

Comment: I think I have resolved the issue... some of the p tags in my sidebar are set to 100% width, which is causing an issue... if I set them to fixed 200px widths for IE only, I believe it will resolve the issue. If it doesn't I will return!